# Breaking the Liskov Subsitute Principle and other academic principles

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I have never been good at recognizing the exact academic issues when conducting code reviews. The following code has a **lot** of issues and I know the solution to fix it, but I want to get better at describing the exact academic principles that are being broken.

Would the `Widget` class break the Liskov Substitute Principle if it were replaced with another instance of `IWidget` such as `Widget2`? Are there any other SOLID principles or academic principles that are being broken?

```
public class ProcessingService
{
    private readonly IWidget _widget;

    ProcessingService(IWidget widget)
    {
        _widget = widget;
    }

    public decimal Process()
    {
        // Fake input for now, but could be any dictionary of objects
        var input = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        return (decimal)_widget.Get(input);
    }
}

public interface IWidget
{
    object Get(Dictionary<string, object> input);
}

public class Widget : IWidget
{
    public object Get(Dictionary<string, object> input)
    {
        var parameter = (int)input["parameter"];

        // Fake some calculation with input and prepare return value....
        var result = 0m;

        return result;
    }
}

public class Widget2 : IWidget
{
    public object Get(Dictionary<string, object> input)
    {
        var parameter = (int)input["parameter"];

        // Fake some calculation with input and prepare return value....
        var result = "Widget String Value";

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Hi gunr2171, I'm not looking for suggestions on how to improve it. However, I'm looking for the guiding academic principles that are not being adhered to. Would that still be a question for CodeReview.SE? Reading the requirements, I don't think this meets their requirements

Comment: I think you would be hard-pressed to call this an infraction of LSP. Your rules are no more or less stringent in the derived implementation, you are not throwing any new and unexpected exceptions, and you are not modifying anything in the base class. That said, this is an excellent example of why variance should be applied via generics as opposed to returning type `object`.

Comment: @gunr2171 This question asks if a specific code implementation violates a specific programming theory rule. That's on-topic enough here, not a request for a general code review.